# Creating Raster with values based on function output

Tags: python, arcmap, raster, open-source-gis

I have a function that calculates a price based on the input slope and distance. I want to write the price to a raster as the rastervalue. How do I do that? OpenSource and ArcMap solutions would work.

```
slopeRaster = "slope.tif"
emptyRaster = "emptyraster.tif" # How do I create an empty raster?
road = "road.shp"

for cell in emptyraster:
    # get slope from sloperaster at cell location
    ...
    slope = ...

    # get distance to nearest road from center of cell
    ...
    distance = ...

    # calculate price for cell
    price = pricefunc(slope, distance)

    # write price to cell as value  # How do I write a value to a raster
```

Comment: Precisely *what* solutions don't work?  This sounds like a straightforward map algebra calculation, which is supported by ArcGIS (the Spatial Analyst extension), GRASS (open source), and all GISes with raster capabilities.

Comment: Well how do I create an empty raster for example with ArcMap and how do I write a value coming from my function to the cells?

Comment: There is no need ever to create an empty raster.  As for the rest, might I suggest you start by looking over the [Spatial Analyst help pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Spatial_Analyst_toolbox/009z00000003000000/).

Comment: In particular, look at the [raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) and the [Slope](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000v2000000.htm) and [EucDistance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000001p000000.htm) functions.